# IDEA IntelliJ git clone

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am new to git and IntelliJ. I would like to get the source code for a project from a remote git repository and work on it using IntelliJ. I am use to Eclipse and SVN which has a "Checkout as Project" dialog.

I tried using "Check out from version control" but w/o any success.

- As the "GIT Repo URL" I entered `git+ssh://user@devserver.dev.org:/var/git/myProject`
- As the "Parent Dir" I added local directory `/home/myName`
- As the "Dir Name" I added `myProject`

I pressed the clone button and nothing happend on the IDE. It does create the directory `/home/myName/myProject` with the `.git` configs but nothing has been fetched from the remote repository nor has the "New Project" Wizzard come up.

Can someone shed some light on how this would be done using IntelliJ and Git compared to Eclipse and SVN? I am using IDEA 10.5 and Fedora LINUX OS.

Comment: Did you verify the connection to the remote repository with the test button as recommended in [To clone a remote Git repository](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/setting-up-a-local-git-repository.html#cloneExistingRepository)?  What OS are you running IDEA on?  What version of IDEA are you running?

Comment: It works now! I didn't try the test button again after it finally stopped complaining about the URL format. However the URL format I used was w/o the prefix git+ssh// Thanks for the hint!

Comment: this will also happen if you are using git and you do not have git installed or IntelliJ is not pointing to the correct git.exe

Answer (score 6):

With IntellIJ 12.0.3 VCS/Check out from Version Control/Git

[image: Check out from Git on Mac]

Answer (score 2):

With `intelliJ`, there is always going to be something that could do with improvement. In this particular instance, you will have a fetching progress indicator at the bottom of your window.

If you create a blank project (with no modules) first, then use the `Version Control -> Checkout from version control -> Git`, you will have a "version control" tab at the bottom of your window where you can at least see the commands sent to git. There is still no progress shown, and if you are lucky like me, it'll sit there silently for ages while git drip feeds the repo with 40kb/s (and we're on a 100 MB connection).

Eventually, it'll allow you to then create a new project for this repo and the tags/branches in your repo will spew out in the version control info panel (that other tab). It works, but its too damn quiet.

Answer (score 0):

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 and this works to clone, import and (optionally) open the project in intelliJ:

```
File --> New --> Project From Version Control...
```